# How to chose connection string in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following problem: My Program uses an `.EDMX` model generated from a SQL database with EF on the .NET framework.

When I work on the program at home from my desktop PC, I use Windows authentication. When I open the program at work, it is necessary to build a new `.EDMX` model with new PC name and standard SQL Server authentication.

How is it possible to change the connection string with a login window for example where I can chose user name, server name and DB name. MS Documentation is not a Help

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your  EDMX-Model class name? for example code I need.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can define the helper to generate a runtime connection string for EDMX. you can find more options for your connection [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string GenerateConnectionString(string server, string database, string username, string password) 
    {
         return  $"data source={server};initial catalog={database};persist security info=True;user id={username};password={password};" +
                $"MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;";
    }
}
```

Then add **contractor** for EDMX Model, for example, my Context model name is [banescoEntities].  "for find context you can type EMDXModelName and use F12 for go to DbContext". shown location on pic. **But be careful if you rebuild Model Context, Mabe needs to rewrite code**

[image]

```
public partial class banescoEntities : DbContext
{
    // add this constractor
    public banescoEntities(string connectionString)
      : base(connectionString)
    {
    }


    public banescoEntities()
        : base("name=banescoEntities")
    {
    }

    // other Context items
}
```

then create instance like :

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // generate ConnectionString runtime
        var cs = Helper.GenerateConnectionString("172.31.4.24\\MSSQLSERVER2019", "banesco", "sa", "blablabal");
        banescoEntities bsEntities = new banescoEntities(cs);

        var products = bsEntities.Products.ToList();
    }
}
```